# History of search terms for evil mode?

Tags: evil, search

When searching for text in evil mode using `/` key, then entering text. The value searched for isn't saved as it is in vim, where the up/down arrow keys can cycle search history.

Is it possible for emacs/evil mode to store each search as it does with `:` commands?

---

Update, `isearch` keys aren't configured for vim-like behavior.

I looked into this and the isearch keymap can be modified, will add own answer.

Comment: Seems this may be a known bug? https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/427

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find things more Vim like with the Evil search module rather than isearch search module with Evil :

```
(evil-select-search-module 'evil-search-module 'evil-search)
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to follow steps in this answer to get it working - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34252236/432509

Comment: Note that using this disables case sensitivity... checking on how to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

To have up/down arrow keys cycle history as with vim, you can define isearch keymap.

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<down>") 'isearch-ring-advance)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<up>") 'isearch-ring-retreat)
```

Comment: Nice answer as it allows to use the usual editing hotkeys you may have configured, while the caret is inside the regexp line. The `'evil-search` from the other answer has its own hotkeys.